# how can i detect if browser is using TLS 1.1 or older

Tags: javascript, java, php, jquery, coldfusion

I want to know how can i disable my website access if the TLS version of browser being used is 1.1 lower, i mean 1.1 is allowed, but anything lower than 1.1 will be denied access. I am using coldfusion server ide language and i am not sure how should i approach this, i tried checking some questions over here in stack overflow but all are java related and i can get the list of headers using CGI but not sure how in CGI variables i can make sure that browser is still using old TLS or new, if there any way of checking this in java internal methods, i can try that but as of now looking for a simplistic way so this can be achieved

Please guide

Thanks

i can do

which shows data like this

[image: https://prnt.sc/wqano7zNeOiB]

i have tried the cgi dump to see if i can use that to handle it

Comment: You set this at the web server end. In the virtual host for the secure SSL connection. You specify that you are only prepared to accept a specific verion(s). this is then sorted out in the initial handshake process between browser and server. If browser cannot work with your requirements the connection will be refused

Comment: https://tecadmin.net/enable-tls-in-modssl-and-apache/

Comment: exactly, but how can i write such thing, can i use the cgi scope for this or do i need to write some custom java to handle this

Comment: ok, in my case we are using IIS, how can i do that in IIS to accept TLS 1.1 and above

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+disable+tls+1.0

Answer (score 3):

There's no easy way to detect the TLS from the browser. This is likely better suited for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

As of 2018, you should not allow anything less than TLS 1.2 period. Anything less is insecure and vulnerable to attacks. 2018 is when PayPal and other payment processors enforced it. More fun, we're almost at the point of TLS 1.3 being the minimum.

**Adding a Header**

When TLS 1.2 was new, I had my DevOps guy add a header sent from our load balancer. We then checked the value in the header and displayed a message on the login screen that as of some date, they could no longer log in with an old browser. This affected < 1% of customers.

**Reject from IIS**

Here's an article to disable legacy TLS settings in IIS 10.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/engineering/disable-legacy-tls

If you're on an older version of IIS, you can find ways to disable it via registry changes. However, there's an overall easier way.

**Reject from CloudFlare**

It's a great idea to add https://www.cloudflare.com/ in front of many applications to manage more things than TLS. You can reject requests based on IP address and handle compression and static caching as well. Once you put this in front of your site, all requests go through it. Rejecting legacy TLS is a breeze:

1. Log in to the Cloudflare dashboard and select your account.
2. Select your website.
3. Go to SSL/TLS > Edge Certificates.
4. For Minimum TLS Version, select an option.

[image: CLoudFlare TLS Settings]